# Text in JFrame title bar for particular text field

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

How can I get the title bar of my JFrame to change to whatever text is inside a particular text field? I've been looking all over the internet for a relevant solution to this but unfortunately none of the results that I've seen solve this issue. All relevant help would be very much appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class Frame extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public Frame() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    private void initComponents() {

        jTextFieldTitle = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTextFieldTitle.setText("jTextField1");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(156, 156, 156)
                .addComponent(jTextFieldTitle, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(185, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(65, 65, 65)
                .addComponent(jTextFieldTitle, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(215, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Frame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        DocumentListener documentListener = new DocumentListener() {
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
                jFrame.setTitle(jTextFieldTitle.getText());
            }

            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
                jFrame.setTitle(jTextFieldTitle.getText());
            }

            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
                jFrame.setTitle(jTextFieldTitle.getText());
            }
        };
        jTextFieldTitle.getDocument().addDocumentListener(documentListener);
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldTitle;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

[image: document listener error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I get the title bar of my JFrame to change to whatever text is inside a particular text field

Your question is about a JTextField and a JFrame. Why did you post all that irrelevant code? To demonstrate a problem create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to post with your question.

Anyway, add a `DocumentListener` to the Document of the text field in question. Whenever the Document changes you can update the frame using the setTitle(...) method and the text from the Document.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for more information and working examples. If you need more help then post a proper `SSCCE` showing what you have tried.

Comment: @MacaronLover, we don't care about all your code. The point of a `SSCCE` is to simplify the problem. A JButton is NOT relevant to your question, so we don't want to see the code. You have multiple text fields and we don't know which one to want to use to change the frame title so all the other text fields are irrelevant to the question. We don't have time to read hundreds of lines of code when only 10-15 are relevant to the question. Read the `SSCCE` link and read the tutorial for the answer to your question.